# How to spy and test whether "useNavigate" method is being called or not of react-router-dom package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to add spy on "useNavigate" method of react-router-dom package to test whether its being called or not on navigation. But I am getting this error "TypeError: Cannot redefine property: useNavigate"

app.js

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
.......
return (
 <a href="" data-testid={recipe.id} onClick={() => {
    console.log("called");
    navigate(`/recipes/edit/${recipe.id}`, {state: {recipe: recipe}});
    }}>
    Edit
 </a>
```

app.test.js

```
import * as ReactRouterDom from "react-router-dom";

const useNavigateSpy = jest.spyOn(ReactRouterDom, "useNavigate");

it("clicking on edit takes to edit view", async() => {
    useNavigateSpy.mockImplementation(() => jest.fn());
    
    await act(async () =>
      render(<BrowserRouter>
        <List />
      </BrowserRouter>));

      const user = userEvent.setup();
      await user.click(screen.getByTestId("R1"));

      expect(useNavigateSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();

  });
```

I can see that that "called" is getting printed, so click is working but yes I am not able to test if navigate is getting called or not.

Any guidance will be really useful.

Comment: Why are you testing code you don't own? What is the use case for testing the `react-router-dom` `useNavigate` hook? Or rather, what you trying to test in *your* code?

Comment: @DrewReese Sorry I didn’t get you. Could you please explain in details